# PHP Problems with using the $_POST with and insert statement

Tags: php, sql, post

```
<?php 
$name = $_POST['usrname'];
$review = $_POST['usrcomment'];
$con = mysqli_connect("host","user","password","db");
if (mysqli_connect_errno()){
   echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}
else {
  $sql="INSERT INTO Feedback (ClientName, ClientComment) VALUES('$name','$review')";
  mysqli_query($con,$sql);
}
if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql)){
   die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
}
mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Here is the error statement: Notice: Undefined index: usrname.

I am trying to connect a web form to a database. I am getting an error of an undefined index for the text field of my web form. I used an SQL insert statement with a $_POST function to insert the data from the web form to the database. I removed the post function from the statement and put in it's place some real data. The statement worked and put the information into the database. It would seem that the error is with the post function. Got any ideas.
Thanks, 
Matt

Comment: can you post your code and the exact error?

Comment: `Notice: Undefined index` occurs when you try to use an array key that does not exist. It could be that either it is not set yet - using `$_POST['username']` on initial page load without posting the form/form element `<input name="username" />` - or misspelling the array key `<input name="username" />`/`$_POST['uname']`

Comment: tell us the output of this: `echo '<pre>';print_r($_REQUEST);echo '</pre>'`

Answer (score 0):

Use `var_dump($_POST)` to debug the problem.  Chances are the name of your input field in the webform is not matching up with the index you are using with `$_POST`.  Also make sure your webform is using`POST` not `GET`

Answer (score 0):

Theres a couple of things that we can do to solve the issue. 
1. Make sure the `action =` is poining to the correct php file
2. Copy the `name` attribute of the element you're trying to use and past that into the key area for `$_POST['']` so if you have `<input type = "text" name = "user">` your variable will look like `$user = $_POST['user'];`
3. `print_r` the array. One function that every php programmer should have is

```
function printarray($printarray){ 
    echo '<pre>';
        print_r($printarray);
    echo '</pre>';
}
```

then every time you need to print your globals use:

```
printarray($_REQUEST);
```

and BAM theres all of your sent variables

Comment: I tried the function and the array is empty. The form points to the right php file, and is set to post. The names of the input types are correct.

Comment: @MattGraham There is nothing else wrong with your code that i can tell, the error you are getting typically comes from the name field being incorrect and then calling on the wrong post value. however since your `print_r` of your global sent variables was empty that also means that the other field you have was empty right? which leads me to believe that you are doing a page refresh or redirect somewhere in your code.